# how to Get real IP address without using site request ? c#

Tags: c#, networking, ip

as you can see I am using below code to get any real ip address on any PC connected to the internet but I was wondering if there is way to get the real IP address without calling a site to get it ?

and if there is a way to send it to my hotmail/gmail/...etc account as email 
i found many ways on the internet but all of them are blocked by mail servers

```
        private string getExternalIp()
    {
        try
        {
            string externalIP;
            externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                         .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
            return externalIP;

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Call Technical Support", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your IP address should be on your network interface. Why would you need to employ an external site to get that?

Comment: He wants the public IP when behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reliable method to get external IP address without actually connecting to something. This is because your machine may be behind NAT and simply doesn't have information what is it's external IP address.

Of course if you know this machine has configured it's external IP address on one of it's interfaces, you may list all interfaces using [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx).